# How to assign the data of a Column of a Table in Databases to a Variable in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

[Table "pilotrun" & Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPdKl.png)

The data type of this variable should be Single Array ().

Like: Dim km_range() As Single = {10, 50, 50, 100}

How to do it in VB.Net

Comment: You might need to update your question with a little more detail, clear concise explanation of what you're attempting and why what you've tried isn't meeting requirements

Comment: There is plenty of information out there about how to work with databases so you should be able to do that part for yourself at least. How to copy data from that data structure to an array is then something you should be able to at least make a start on. *"I want to do X, show me how"* is not a question for SO. You need to learn how and try for yourself, then ask us if and when you encounter an actual issue.